# Is this protecting route solution for Nextjs usable?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

import Login from './index';
import auth from '../services/authService';

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const router = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    const user = auth.getCurrentUser();
    setUser(user);

    if (!user) return router.replace('/');
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

Here-

- `Login` component contains the login form.
- `auth.getCurrentUser()` returns jwt decoded user object.

I do not want any page except login page to be accessible by a unauthorized user. Will it even work? I am looking for a good solution for this problem.

Comment: This thread might be useful: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13610

Answer (score 0):

i suggest to use **react context** :

for example :

```
 1-create usercontext
    export const UserContext = createContext(initialUser) 
 2- then create userprovider 
    UserProvider : 
     <UserContext.Provider value={initialUser}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
 3- for example:
    initialUser ={
      user :{USER_DATA},
      isLogin : true | false //if cookie set or user exist ? true : false
    }
    you can fetch USER_DATA from api or internet
```

**also UserProvider :**

```
const checkAuth = () =>{ ... }

const logout = () =>{ ... }
 
const storeUser = user => { ... }

return <UserContext.Provider value={initialUser}>{children}. 
       </UserContext.Provider>
```

**in _app**

```
import { UserProvider, UserContext } from "PATH_TO_CONTEXT/UserConext";

const initialUser = useContext(UserContext)

<UserProvider >
 {initialUser.isLogin ? <Component {...pageProps} /> : <Login {...pageProps} />}
</UserProvider>
```

as you see i used UserProvider as parent component so each route can access to user info or login info.